# How to use react router flux from start second page

Tags: react-native

I implemented react native router (react-native-router-flux) after implemented its works fine but i need to start it from home page not my first login page .

Router code I implemented react native router (react-native-router-flux) after implemented its works fine but i need to start it from home page not my first login page.

Here is my code:

router code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, Button, Navigator, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Router, Route, Schema, Actions, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import login from './main/login';
import home from './main/home';
import flexcontent from './main/flexcontent';
import SideDrawer from './main/SideDrawer';
import Screen1 from './main/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './main/Screen2';
export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
render() {
    return (
    <SideDrawer ref={c => { c ? this.drawer = c.drawer : this.drawer }}>
     <Router key="root">
        <Scene key="pages">
         <Scene key="login" component={login} title="login" initial={true} />
          <Scene key="home" component={home} title="home"/>
          <Scene key="Screen1" component={Screen1} title="Screen1"/>
          <Scene key="Screen2" component={Screen2} title="Screen2"/>
          <Scene name='Drawer' key="flexcontent" component={flexcontent} title="flexcontent"/>
         </Scene>
        </Router>
       </SideDrawer>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    leftButtonContainer: {
        paddingLeft: 15,
        paddingRight: 20,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
})



Sidedrawercontent.js page code:

import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, } from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button'
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'
export default class SideDrawerContent extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        drawer: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    render() {
        const { drawer } = this.context
        return (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={() => { drawer.close(); Actions.home.call() }}>{'home'}</Button>
                <Button onPress={() => { drawer.close(); Actions.Screen1.call() }}>{'Screen 1'}</Button>
                <Button onPress={() => { drawer.close(); Actions.Screen2.call() }}>{'Screen 2'}</Button>
                <Button onPress={() => { drawer.close();Actions.login.call() }}>{'Logout'}</Button>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

SideDrawerContent.propTypes = {
    drawer: PropTypes.object
}
```

I am using this https://github.com/efkan/rndrawer-implemented-rnrouter route in my app

Comment: You want to always start from home instead of login?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There's no need to manually type Enter in your paragraphs here, Monika. Just type your paragraph in a long line, and it will line-break automatically, just like HTML. To separate paragraphs, use double-Enter.

Comment: no i want first my login page after that home page but i need side menu on home page not in login page right now its comes from login page

Answer (score 1):

**Change initial props login page to home page like below :**

```
<Scene key="home" component={home} title="home" initial={true}/>
<Scene key="login" component={login} title="login"  />
```

- initial props indicate starting page of the application.

Answer (score 0):

The `initial={true}` prop assigned to the login `<Scene/>` tells it to load first. If none it assigned it will load whatever `<Scene/>` is listed first. So to make the home `<Scene/>` be the first screen you see assign initial to that `<Scene/>`. You can also omit `={true}`

```
<Scene key="login" component={login} title="login" />
  <Scene key="home" component={home} title="home" initial />
```

Comment: I need my first page is login page when i click on login button its comes on home page after that i need menu on home page

Comment: Here's a sample for you to look at: https://gist.github.com/MattyK14/567c08f218cfec359bfb938283a41d23
You want to wrap your home `<Scene />` with a another `<Scene />` that has the `component={SideDrawer}`